# Does bufferedReader close the reader after reaching EOF?

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that uses a BufferedReader to read from a file and marks the current position of the reader so that I can reset to the last line when I need to. However I'm getting an I/O exception and I'm not positive why. This piece of code is in a bigger loop that also utilizes the read method which is why I'm resetting when I encounter "From:".

```
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null && line.indexOf("From:")!=0) {   
    emailMsg.append(line).append("\n");
    reader.mark(0);
}

reader.reset(); //io exception: mark invalid
emailMsg.append(".\n");
```

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: The one with the comment next to it `reader.reset()`

Comment: Oops; should have seen that. Too early in the morning for me. :)

Comment: Just to be sure - your input file has at least one line without "From:" at the beginning?

Comment: What is the full text of the exception? Does it specify a reason?

Comment: Indeed it does. It seems strange to me that it wouldn't mark the last valid line before either reaching "from" or eof and then just re-read it on the bigger loop when it goes back up to the top

Comment: It simply says `java.IOException:mark invalid`. It is getting thrown when it reaches EOF but the way the code is constructed the assumption was it would reset to the line right before so that when it does reach EOF in this loop, it will allow the loop higher up to read it and break out

Comment: I think you should call reader.mark(0) BEFORE reading anything...

Comment: I could, but then I cannot reset to the most recently read line in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to `mark()` is the `readAheadLimit`. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29):

> `readAheadLimit` - Limit on the number of characters that may be read while still preserving the mark. An attempt to reset the stream after reading characters up to this limit or beyond may fail. A limit value larger than the size of the input buffer will cause a new buffer to be allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large values should be used with care.

Since you have specified `0`, and the next `readLine()` call ends up reading something from the stream, the subsequent `reset` has a possibility of failing since you are over the limit.

When you tell the stream to "mark" a location, you specify a read-ahead limit, which basically tells the stream to "remember" that many characters. As long as you *don't* read past the limit, you can call `reset()` how many ever times you want and it will reset it back to the beginning of that "remembered" set of characters. Once you read *past* that limit however, the mark is invalid and so subsequent calls to `reset()` will fail. In your case, you have specified a read-ahead limit of `0`, which means *any* read past the current point will invalidate the mark, which is what you are seeing.

To get around this, specify a non-zero read-ahead limit.

Comment: I read that as well and was experimenting with what value I should use since the point was, if I read a line that begins with "From" to reset the buffer to keep from skipping ahead (since there is no peek method in bufferedReader). What's odd is that it does not fail except on EOF

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks, like the line you read from reader does not contain "From:" sequence, so execution does not enter while-loop, so the mark is not set, and when execution continues right after while-loop body, `reset` throws an exception, because the mark was not set, as per [reset() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#reset%28%29).

You rather need this:

```
boolean marked = false;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.indexOf("From:") != 0) {
        continue;
    }
    emailMsg.append(line).append('\n');
    reader.mark(0);
    marked = true;
}
if (marked) {
    reader.reset();
    emailMsg.append('\n');
}
```

Comment: It definitely enters the while loop, it just breaks out when it reaches EOF. And then throws an exception right afterwards at mark

Comment: `line != null && line.indexOf("From:") != 0` means enter the loop if there's actually a line AND it DOES NOT contain "From:" at the very first place (in first column which index is 0). So if the first line starts with "From:" it will not enter the loop as the condition is not met and it will skip directly to `reset`.

Comment: There is a larger loop as I said, I didn't feel it was relevant and so did not post it. There's a lot of extra irrelevant code in the larger loop that would only distract from the problem